# window.location.replace() is not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, redirect

just wanna ask why does window.location.replace is not working in my page. I've been working on it for weeks. It works fine on my other pages, although those pages have DevExpress components, but in this particular page where I am only using normal html and asp tags and components it is not working. It seems to be refreshing only and not redirecting. Here is my code for the button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCancelValidatePassword" runat="server" 
                        CausesValidation="False" ClientIDMode="AutoID" CssClass="ButtonControl" 
                        Height="30px" OnClientClick="window.location.replace('../Account/Settings.aspx')" Text="CANCEL" Width="100px" />
```

Thanks.

Comment: if you're using firefox, open Error Console (CTRL+SHIFT+J)...do you see any error?

Comment: Hi, I received a lot of warnings and 2 errors: (1) TypeError: defaultEngine is null (2)
AboutHOmeUtils.defaultSearch is undefined

Comment: Fix that error or you can post the error in your question so the other can help you.

Comment: my page is in a secured window. Does it have something to do with my issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with it not working when reloading same page in **Chrome**. Doing the following worked:

```
   window.location.replace("/mypage1.aspx?type=abc"); //redirect to fake page
   window.location.replace("/mypage.aspx?type=abc");  //redirect to same page
```

It is a bit of a hack, but this seems to be the only thing that forces a reload on the same page in Chrome. IE and FF work without the redirect to a fake page.

Answer (score -5):

`.replace()` is a method of the `String` object

`window.location` is not a string. Use `window.location.href` instead and call `.replace()` on `window.location.href`.

```
window.location.href.replace(/string_to_be_replaced/, 'string_to_replace');
```

Comment: `window.location.replace` is a function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location